# Get string between 2 characters Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex and it really confuses me. What I am trying to accomplish is finding the string between 2 specified characters where the string should contain another specified character within it.

String Example: 'Help--Me'

In this case I would be looking for the string Help Me that's between the two apostrophes and contains -- in it.

The Regex I have currently is `@"(?<=\')(--.*?)(?=\')"`
This seems to only work if the -- is at the beginning of the string 
Example: '--HelpMe'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close—nice attempt. You need another wildcard string at the beginning:

```
@"(?<=\')(.*?--.*?)(?=\')"
```

This way, it'll look for a string of any characters following the `'` (the *minimum* string, by the way, due to the non-greedy quantifier, `*?`), a `--`, another string of any characters (again, the minimum string), and finally the closing `'`.